# Custom playlist saving/retrieving

Tags: ios

I have an app that allows the user to build a simple playlist which is stored as an array of  `MPMediaItem`s. When the app quits or enters the background, I want to store the playlist in a file and retrieve it when the user opens the app again.

Should I just be saving an id in a file as opposed to a whole `MPMediaItem` object?

Also, as the user's library may have changed how would I compare the saved list against the iPod library, do I loop through and run a bunch of queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save this array into plist file, which is a effective way to save and read from local file. 
Here in below are metheds to create, save, read data from plist. Hope it is helpful for you.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *doc = [paths    objectAtIndex:0]; //path of document folder
NSString *path = [doc stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"nameOfPlist.plist"];   //get the path of your plist in document folder.

NSDictionary* dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"123456",@"number", nil]; //save your data into a dictionary or array.
[dic writeToFile:path atomically:YES];  //then write the dic/array into the plist file.

NSDictionary* dic2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];  //read data from plist.
NSLog(@"dic2 is:%@",[dic2 objectForKey:@"number"]);
```

Comment: Thanks Lothario. I was using array writeToFile which wasn't working but I'll try this and let you know how I go.

Comment: NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *path = [paths    objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filename = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];
    NSArray *write = @[@"1",@"2",@"3"];
    [write writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];